# Obtener cantidad de quincenas en un año

Tags: sql-server, transact-sql

Tengo una consulta , como puedo obtener el numero de quincenas de una tabla base de datos
ejemplo

```
15/01/2020 (1)

30/01/2020 (2)

15/02/2020 (3)

28/02/2020 (4) y así sucesivamente
```

En un campo `fecha_fin` de planilla

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta puede ser muy amplia, pero según lo que entendí, el siguiente código genera 24 filas para mostrar todas las quincenas en un año.

```
DECLARE @Año CHAR(4) = '2020';

SELECT CASE WHEN Q.n = 1 --Si es quincena
                THEN DATEADD( DD, 14, DATEADD(MM, M.n, @Año)) --Sumamos 14 días al primero del mes
            ELSE EOMONTH( DATEADD(MM, M.n, @Año)) --Si no, obtenemos el último día
            END AS fecha_fin,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY M.n, Q.n DESC) -- Generamos el consecutivo de quincenas
FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)) M(n) --Generamos números para los meses
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(1))Q(n) --Generamos filas para saber si es quincena o fin de mes
ORDER BY M.n, Q.n DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias funciono la instruccion que enviaste, la ajuste a mis necesidades

Comment: Recuerda no realizar comentarios como respuesta, debajo de tu pregunta puedes agregar los comentarios.